# sonar 4.3: How to push xml output to sonar dashboard

Tags: sonarqube

We have written on tool to do some certain quality check on code. Now we want to integrate that tool to sonar and push the result on sonar dashboard. 
Just wanted to know how to do it. Let's say my tool output is in xml format.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the Sonar .NET Tests library as a reference. It imports generated coverage reports in XML format into SonarQube. A possible starting point is this class:

https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-dotnet-tests-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/dotnet/tests/CoverageAggregator.java